# Windows WPR (recorder) not capturing Write event

Tags: java, strace

I am using WPR to capture underlining I/O calls from Java application on Windows. It appears, WPR does not always capture Write events. However, the bytes do end up in the file. This was a test of memory-mapped IO. My environment is Windows 8 and Java 7. How is it possible for WPR to miss "Writes" if the file is changed?

Thanks